# Open an already opened (by others) Excel file with BATCH

Tags: windows, excel, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a BATCH code, which perfectly opens an EXCEL file:

```
START "C:\office\excel.exe" "C:\tmp\file.xlsx"
```

**BUT:** If someone else opens this EXCEL file (via network) and do not close it --> he leaves it opened, then I cannot open this file using my BATCH.

If I click on the EXCEL file, and press ENTER (so opening using windows not batch), the file will be opened, but it alerts me that someone else is locked this file, but I can open it to read or I can request a notice if the other person closes the file.

How could I set in BATCH file, to open the EXCEL (or WORD) file (only for reading) even if it is opened by others (via network)?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Excel-321cf55a-ace4-40b3-9082-53bd4bc10725?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: ahhh.. so the solution is to leave the START command. thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: leave the `START` command:

```
"C:\office\excel.exe" "C:\tmp\file.xlsx"
```

Comment: I'd suggest the solution is the use of the /r switch : `START "C:\office\excel.exe" /r "C:\tmp\file.xlsx"`